# Meaning of "deviance" when using glmnet and family = "binomial"

Tags: r, logistic, glmnet, deviance, scoring-rules

When using glmnet in R with

```
family = "binomial"
```

you can set

```
type.measure = "class"
```

or

```
type.measure = "deviance"
```

Is this measure of "deviance" in some way related to the Brier Score?

Comment: Regarding specifying `type.measure = mse` in cv.glmnet with binary data, I have noticed that the MSE-values returned by cv.glmnet are somehow scaled [and I have posted this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75604698/does-cv-glmnet-in-r-return-double-mse-for-binary-data) asking if anyone knows why this happens. I find this very confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, deviance is different from the Brier Score. Deviance here is the standard definition, i.e. twice the difference between the saturated log-likelihood and the fitted log-likelihood (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviance_(statistics)) whereas Brier score is the average squared difference between the observed outcomes and the fitted probabilities (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brier_score). If you want to use Brier score as your measure, use `type.measure = mse`

If you want to see the difference programmatically, inspect lines 42-52  of `glmnet:::cv.lognet`